# How do I display only the headlines from a feed? Modx/spieFeed

Tags: modx, simplepie, modx-revolution

I am using ModX Revolution and have installed spieFeed as a RSS Feed Reader. I want to display only the headlines with links in a div on the page. I would also like to set a maximum number of articles and sort by most recent.

I can't make heads or tails of the Usage instructions, or where in ModX I would edit the code. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ModX, but search your files for this:

```
[[!spieFeed
```

and you should find where it's called. Note that [spieFeed](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/spieFeed) is based on SimplePie 1.2, latest version is 1.3.x. It may be difficult to do what you're attempting...

Answer (score 0):

1. Duplicate the chunk "defaultSpieFeedTpl"
2. Edit the content of the new chunk to fit your need.
3. add &tpl to the snippet call using the new chunk `[[!spieFeed? &tpl=`myNewChunk`]]`

@Revent,
It's been updated to the 1.3 though, the http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/spiefeed needed to be updated.